# Angular 1/Jasmine - Test return type of function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test the return type of a function, is it a boolean or a number ...

With this code I test whether the function exists or not, how can I push the test by testing the return type ?

```
it('should expose a showMonthlyRentDate function', () => {
  expect(ctrl.showMonthlyRentDate).toBeDefined()
   expect(typeof ctrl.showMonthlyRentDate).toBe('function')
 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

```
expect(ctrl.showMonthlyRentDate()).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
```

It is preferable to use `jasmine.any` since it provides more meaningful feedback on test fail.